# Set the default value for date_range in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How Can I setup default value in rails 4. I am trying

```
filter :by_resolved_at_in, as: :date_range,label: "Filtro Resolvido em", :value => Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is `ActiveAdmin`, right?

You can't do this in the `filter` line but you can define a `before_filter` where the ransack values are initialized.

```
  before_filter :only => [:index] do
    if params['commit'].blank?
       params['q'] = {by_resolved_at_in: Date.today..Date.today} 
    end
  end
```